# Disable Google Glass's 10 Seconds Video Default Setting

Tags: google-glass

Right now `MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA` will start recording using the Google Glass camera for 10 seconds (user must press button to extend recording length). Is there anyway to disable this?

Screenshot: http://imgur.com/zLElYoa

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to change this default (appears to have been set to help with battery life). Whether this will change in next release of software is unknown.

You can, of course, create your own GDK app that works differently ... but this does not seem to be the gist of your question.